# Geolocation - Assign the latitude and longitude values to variables

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I followed the examples on how to get current position (longitude and latitude) in javascript and have tried it and works fine.

My issue is with assigning the lng and lat values to variables so that i can always reuse them. I understand the function is some sort of async call.

From the example below, within the showPosition function my current location is printed (fine as expected!) but out the function prints undefined.

What is the best way to get the lat ang lng values so that they can be used in other functions.

```
var lat;
var lng;
// users current location using HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        lat = position.coords.latitude; 
        lng = position.coords.longitude;
        console.log("lat: " + lat + "lng: " + latlng); // works fine prints current position
    }

    console.log("lat: " + lat + "lng: " + latlng); // prints undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a scope issue .. try declaring the vars outside the function

```
var lat;
var lng;

// users current location using HTML5 geolocation.

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
}

function showPosition(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude; 
    lng = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log("lat: " + lat + "lng: " + latlng); // works fine prints current position
}

console.log("lat: " + lat + "lng: " + latlng); // prints undefined
```

Comment: Have updated the question. the variables were defined outside the function.